# Specific link for a content type

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, media

I created a content type with 3 file fields, and I want all fields to have a specific link.

For example:

1. file field :file281
2. file field :file282
3. file field :file283

Because, I want put background image on this fields. How can I do this?

Comment: Your acceptance rate is quite low. Maybe you should consider accepting answers from your previous posts and upvoting those that were relevant. This way,  *the help you received will help others*. See [this awesome faq](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq) for more juicy details on how this community operates. Cheers!

Comment: My pleasure friend.